# Im l'eit kazot higa'at lamalchut - mi yodeya?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

### Who knows if you come to royalty for a time like this?

### ?אם לעת כזאת, הגעת למלכות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Shoshanat Ya'akov"](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/1513/jewish/Shoshanat-Yaakov.htm), please post interesting Jewish facts about the significance of your ascent to royalty.

The [lazy gematria](http://www.thetrugmans.com/trugman_gematria.shtml) for this one is [Joshua 6:19](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0606.htm#19).

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-four entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I just got how the title is a play on the pasuk.

Comment: @DoubleAA, same thing with [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26189/mah-tov-la-adam-bachayim-mi-yodeya). It's amazing how many contributions to this song / [references to this website](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1478/2) are in Tanach. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Yalkut Me'am Loez, this conversation took place in year 3404.

In the Jewish Calendar, one normally counts without the "thousands" (Tof Shin Ayin instead of Heih Tof Shin Ayin).

Therefore, in addition to Mordechai telling Queen Esther "Listen, you got in so we don't go [404](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/this_doesn%27t_Exist) (look at that picture)", 404 is also the Gematria of

- אחד לא שווה לאחד - you got in and "one isn't equal to another" - therefore, only you can go in.
- נקבים נקבים  - you got into power so we shouldn't get stabbed with many holes.
- עבודה חדשה  - You got into power to practice Shtadlanus - a "new service" which was never practiced before.
- קיבוץ עלומים - You got into power to do "Kibutz Olamim" - to gather all the Jew into praying for you.
- טשולנט - You must introduce Achashveirosh to Cholent (She being Sefardi, it must have been spicy  and resulted in Achashveiroshe's wrath).
- לא עלינו ולא עליכם  - If you don't go, I don't envy you or us.