# Meat and dairy shamir worms?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If I used a shamir to cut through over-baked colov yisroel NY pizza and also to penetrate my mother-in-law's dry meatloaf, would I need one shamir worm for meat and the other for dairy, or can I use the same worm for both?

And if I need to keep separate shamir worms, can I still wrap them in wool and keep them in the same lead container?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: wouldn't the worm just have to wait 6 hours? Or less if he's Dutch?

Comment: He could be Dutch, but I forgot to think about if he was shamir negiah. In that case, separate lead jars would best.

Answer (score 4):

Chalav is an acronym of chesed lev, the mother's kindness to the child. Basar is an acronym of beis sar, the house of a prince, as poor people do not eat meat.

We do not combine these concepts so a mother's love is never jaundiced by physical acquisitions.

Shamir is an acronym for shin mar, because when it cuts through pizza it leaves a bitter taste. Therefore it is nosen taam liphgam and the same worm can be used for meat and milk.