# Why was dill created just before Shabbat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Pirkei Avot 5:6:

> עֲשָׂרָה דְבָרִים נִבְרְאוּ בְעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת בֵּין הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת,
> וְאֵלּו הֵן....  וְהַשָּׁמִיר,:

Ten things were created on the eve of the [first] Shabbat at twilight. And these are they: ... the dill

I see that all the other items in the list were used either for some other miracle / event mentioned in the Torah or in the Temple. Point is, that they are mentioned somewhere in Tanac"h. Where was dill mentioned in Tanac"h; What was its use?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26338/759

Answer (score 5):

Dill is called שָׁמִיר in this *mishna* but in *Tanach* it's called [שֶׁבֶת](//he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%92_%D7%91).

King David sings the praises of dill ([Ps. 133](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T26d3)):

> הִנֵּה מַה טּוֹב וּמַה נָּעִים [שֶׁבֶת](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%92_%D7%91)
>   Lo, what is good, and what is pleasant? Dill!

Indeed, dill adds flavor to a variety of foods, whether sweet, savory, or bland. King Solomon followed his father's lead, writing ([Ps. 127](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T26c7)):

> שָׁוְא לָכֶם… מְאַחֲרֵי שֶׁבֶת אֹכְלֵי לֶחֶם הָעֲצָבִים
>   A waste of time for you… who add dill too late! You are eaters of sad bread.

Dill's importance in Judaism is evidenced by its growing on Mount Sinai when God gave the Torah there ([Deut. 1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%95)):

> ה׳ אֱלֹקֵינוּ דִּבֶּר אֵלֵינוּ בְּחֹרֵב לֵאמֹר רַב לָכֶם שֶׁבֶת בָּהָר הַזֶּה
>   God, our god, spoke to us on Sinai saying: There is much dill for you on this mountain.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is a just a personal opinion:

I think it was created so close to Shabbat so that Eve would not have time to put it in the chicken soup!

Comment: Why did God care if Eve had time to put it in the soup?

Comment: Cos he didn't want her to upset Adam more than she had already done so.