# Why didn't Esther listen to Mordechai's instructions?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Mordechai instructed Esther the Queen,

> וּמִי יוֹדֵעַ אִם לְעֵת כָּזֹאת הִגַּעַתְּ לַמַּלְכוּת

Translation:

> Ask on [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) if this is the reason you came to be a Queen.

(It seems that the term Mi Yodeya was used as the term Google is nowadays, e.g "just Google it", - "just Mi Yodeya it.")

Why didn't Esther ask the question on Mi Yodeya?
Could she have been scared that rule-following nudniks would close her question as off-topic?
Wouldn't Mordechai HaTazddaik have reopened her question for her?

Are we to assume that he would have held less of a Reputation than the closure crowd?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: She [tried](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15061/im-leit-kazot-higaat-lamalchut-mi-yodeya), and it *was* closed!

Answer (score 13):

Who says she didn't? I have image proof that she did!

[image: "Mi Yodeya" question asking "Why did I become queen?"]

Comment: Close as [RFפ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3406/759)

Comment: ...and someone went and [actually posted this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55338/why-did-i-become-queen).

Comment: @Yehuda No JS, i just edited the HTML directly on a downloaded copy of a page.

Comment: @Cnsersmoit oh, well you could have pasted this line into the browser of any page. `javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0`

Comment: 12 gold badges, and only 4321 reputation?

Comment: About the numbers: 661 is gematriya of אסתר, the 761 bronze badges is the gematriya of אסתר המלכה, while 12 and 14 (gold/silver) are the date of Purim 12th month (Adar), 14th day.

Answer (score 6):

Esther knew better than Mordechai that questions about Jewish history unless related to Judaism, are off topic. Why she became queen was history, at the time, and, Esther was not allowed to reveal that she was Jewish! (Read the Megilla yourself!) So, there was no way that she could even phrase her question to show that it was related to Judaism without risking her life.

... Kapish???

Answer (score 5):

Esther held that using the internet is forbidden.  That's why her response was

> לך כנוס את כל היהודים הנמצאים בשושן
>
> Go gather all of the Jews found in Shushan

Esther, seeing how prominent the internet had become, convened the first Internet Asifa.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language/80570#80570

Comment: @Ypnypn not following.

Comment: My point is that Kinnus and Aisfa may not be the same.

Answer (score 5):

Esther *would* have followed Mordechai's instructions, but Achashverosh's IT department were all at the party and maintenance fell by the wayside.  This is why we learn (Esther 8:9-11) that the king now relies on scribes and horseback messengers to disseminate his decrees instead of posting on Facebook -- and surely if even the *king* cannot get reliable network access for *official announcements*, then we should not expect Esther to be able to access Mi Yodeya or even Google.

> And they wrote in the name of king Ahasuerus, and sealed it with the king's ring, and sent letters by posts on horseback, riding on swift steeds that were used in the king's service, bred of the stud;

Comment: That explains why she instructed `לך כנוס את כל היהודים הנמצאים בשושן` and she didnt just post it on Facebook!